# Create multiple objects resulting from a loop of paste(list.files)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, sapply

I have multiple folders such as `"results/[model_name_here]/rasters/"`  and I'm trying to create multiple objects resulting from a loop of `list.files`. For example:

```r
model_a <- list.files("results/rf/rasters", pattern = "tif$", full.names = TRUE)
```

I was trying to go for a `for` loop such as

```r
models <- c("rf", "brt", "gam", "glm",
            "mars", "bart", "svm")

for (i in models) {
  i <- list.files(paste0("results/", i, "/rasters/"),
                  pattern = "tif$",
                  full.names = TRUE)
  
}
```

But that doesn't work properly. How can I proceed? I don't mind using `sapply` or other type of function. The idea is simply to create, in my case, eight objects, each one called `i` in models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to initialize the result vector (which is a list) first, then in R we usually use the indices. Try this:

```
models <- c("rf", "brt", "gam", "glm", "mars", "bart", "svm")

r <- vector('list', length(models))
for (i in seq_along(models)) {
  r[[i]] <- list.files(paste0("results/", models[i], "/rasters/"), 
                       pattern="tif$", full.names=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: That works for loading the models, thanks! But then I obtain a list of multiple models. I was trying to obtain an object for each model. How can I proceed? Sure, I can extract each one of them, but I was trying to use a loop or sapply to not waste much time

Comment: @hiperhiper Well, you have a list with the models,what more can you ask for. Extract one model `x <- r[[i]]` and write a `f <- funcion(x) {}` that does what you desire. Finally apply it on the list using `lapply(res, f)`.